# Why this code is getting cant convert complex to float? Or I get invalid syntax

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, complex-numbers

```
import numpy as np
import math
freq2 = np.zeros(N)
freq2[2] = 1+(math.pi/2)j
```

Driving me insane... it points to the complex j operator

```
freq2[2] = 1+((math.pi)/2)j
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and then this says

```
freq2[2] = 1+2j
```

Cant convert complex to float

Comment: What's that `j` doing there?

Comment: @Aran-Fey that's Python's way of encoding complex numbers https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html

Comment: @Natalie-Johnson: Can you be a bit more specific in your question? What exact output do you get? Have you already tried anything to fix it? People will be more likely to help if they don't have to run your example themselves to see what the problem is.

Comment: I amended it. Its j, the complex number operator...

Comment: So you're fully aware that you're trying to add a complex number to a numpy array and you're wondering why it doesn't work?

Comment: So what should I be using instead... my apologies...Ive come from MATLAB

Comment: `j` is not an operator. I don't think that would have worked even in MATLAB. (It didn't work when I tried it in Octave just now.)

Comment: `np.zeros` creates a `dtype` float array.  You can't put a complex value in such an array without loosing the imaginary part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `j` operator. `j` is part of the syntax for an imaginary literal. Just like in MATLAB, if you want to convert a real number to imaginary, you should multiply by `1j`, not just stick a `j` on the end of an expression:

```
freq2[2] = 1+(math.pi/2)*1j
```

instead of

```
freq2[2] = 1+((math.pi)/2)j
```

As for the `TypeError`, unlike in MATLAB, you can't stuff a complex number into an array of floats. You need to create the array with a complex dtype from the start:

```
freq2 = np.zeros(N, dtype=complex)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put a complex value in array, the array has to have the correct dtype to start with:

```
In [17]: x = np.zeros(3, dtype=complex)                                         
In [18]: x                                                                      
Out[18]: array([0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j])
In [19]: x[0] = 1 + np.pi/2*1j                                                  
In [20]: x                                                                      
Out[20]: array([1.+1.57079633j, 0.+0.j        , 0.+0.j        ])
```

Or making a complex array from a list of values:

```
In [21]: np.array([1+np.pi/2*1j, 0, 1, 23j])                                    
Out[21]: array([1. +1.57079633j, 0. +0.j        , 1. +0.j        , 0.+23.j        ])
```